# July Graduation Moderator Election - Might you stand?

Tags: discussion, election, graduation

As you know, Lifehacks recently [graduated](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2887/6973) from Beta status.

It's time to hold an election for moderators of the graduated site.

The last election we held was back in [2019](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2741/6973), a pro-tem election.  Since then a couple of moderators have resigned - we thank them for their efforts.

So: we need to hold a new election to install an active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a pulse check to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.  Posting an answer to this question does not commit you to standing in the election when it runs.

**UPDATE** The election is now scheduled for mid-July.  This will be a full Graduation Election, so we need a minimum of four candidates to come forward. The first stage, question collection, will start on Monday 18 July.

Look out for a formal announcement of the election here on meta in early July.

This is your chance to help look after your community.

Comment: Erm… nobody? <Notices a very  tentative twitch in the hand. I definitely don’t need another diamond, but…>